# batch script to prompt for destinations folder list

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to create a folder within the folder in a destination directory:

```
SET initDir=D:\Test-Destination\
SET newDir=
SET /P newDir=Type folder name: %=%

IF DEFINED newDir (
    MD D:\Test-Destination\%newDir%
    SET initDir=%initDir%\%newDir%
)
```

I will input today's date like `13-09-2013` to create directory but when it comes to next month I again need to create two folders like `October>01-0-10-2013` for next year I need to create 3 folders. I need this to always prompt for destination.

Kindly help me to create a batch script.

Comment: The folders you need to create are unclear.  Perhaps they could be automated if you explain what you need again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps: it will keep prompting for folders - just press enter to quit.

```
@echo off
:loop
SET "initDir=D:\Test-Destination"
SET "newDir="
SET /P "newDir=Type folder name: "
IF not DEFINED newDir goto :EOF
MD "%initDir%\%newDir%"
goto :loop
```

Comment: it is creating different folders in the location, but not inside one folder another

Comment: See my comment to your question, above.